# One-liner to proxy and log http traffic?

Tags: http, https, proxy, network-programming

I am looking for a (preferably linux command line) program/one-liner `logtraffic` I can run that will do the following use cases:

```
http client  <-> http server
https client <-> http server
http client  <-> https server
https client <-> https server
```

Basically I want to put a proxy in between my client and the server so that I can see all of the http traffic in cleartext. This is for testing purposes.

So the first use case is covered by netcat, but the other cases are more interesting because they use encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a program [mitmdump](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/mitmdump.html) that does exactly what I want:

```
mitmdump -p 9000 -P https://my.server.net -w traffic.log
```

Comment: I think that should be `-R` instead of `-P`.